# Unable to use postMessage within cordova

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, cordova, postmessage

In our cordova/phonegap-app we're using an iFrame to load external websites. To communicate with the iFrame-content I've created a script for both sites (App and Website) which uses iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage()-method. The reason is to open external links within the iframe in the system-browser of the smartphone. This solution worked fine on cordova 2.3.0.

Today I've updated the cordova version of the app to 3.1.0 and deleted some permissions from android-manifest. But the communication with the iFrame-content doesn't work. Following error error-message is shown:

```
"Unable to post message to https://[domain]. Recipient has origin file://"
```

To post a message to the IFrame I use following code:

```
$('#webViewIFrame').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('message', host);
```

Has anybody an idea why my communication-solution doesn't work with cordova 3.1.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postMessage in PhoneGap not working - iframe to parent messaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554114/postmessage-in-phonegap-not-working-iframe-to-parent-messaging)

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should be because of cross domain problem. Try using this:

```
$('#webViewIFrame').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('message', '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use:

```
$('#webViewIFrame').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('message',"*");
```

Since phonegap/cordova pages are served at "file://" and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

> "...posting a message to a page at a file: URL currently requires that the targetOrigin argument be "*". file:// cannot be used as a security restriction; this restriction may be modified in the future."