# postMessage in PhoneGap not working - iframe to parent messaging

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

I've build a PhoneGap app which which makes use of an iframe which is bundled with the app and I'm am trying to pass e message from the iframe to the parent which doesn't seem to be working when I run the app on an actual iPad; however it works fine when I run the app in the browser on the same device.

Here is the code I'm using inside the iframe to send a message, note that I'm using HammerJS to capture some events:

```
var domain = 'http://' + document.domain;

$('body').hammer().on("swipe", "", function(event) {
    var message = event.gesture.direction;
    parent.postMessage(message,domain); //send the message and target URI
});
```

and the code I'm using to get the message:

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    alert(event.data);
},false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is to use "file://" as the domain name so the code will look like this:

```
var domain = 'file://';

$('body').hammer().on("swipe", "", function(event) {
    var message = event.gesture.direction;
    parent.postMessage(message,domain); //send the message and target URI
});
```

Comment: Not working for me,This is how I am calling from page <a href="javascript:window.open('http://dziban.co.in/test/postmsg.php','_blank','location=no');" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">open window</a>, receiving same as you and tried file:// and http://dziban.co.in/test/postmsg.php in postMessage but no luck. Can you please explain how you opened iframe from html.

Comment: This is not opening an iframe from html, it's about passing data from an iframe to the parent website, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage. As for what you are trying to do you can't open an iframe from JavaScript but you can open a new window you can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma how did you resolve the issue please? We are using `parent.postMessage(message, '*');` and it works on Android but we cannot get it to work on iOS

Comment: @jablesauce did you whitelist the iframe domain? See https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage -> IOS: "To whitelist a domain, add it to the ExternalHosts array in the Cordova.plist file."

Comment: @jablesauce Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with using

```
var domain = '*';
```

Normally this should be because of cross domain problem, [see more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use:

```
parent.postMessage(message,"*");
```

Since phonegap/cordova pages are served at "file://" and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

> "...posting a message to a page at a file: URL currently requires that the targetOrigin argument be "*". file:// cannot be used as a security restriction; this restriction may be modified in the future."